# fixed navbar code isn't great and it's causing problems with the links breaking and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm not quite sure how to explain the problem, but essentially, my fixed navbar either doesn't scroll, but the hyperlinks work, or the navbar scrolls but the hyperlinks don't work. This cycle keeps happening while I try to fix it in html and css. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Here is the html for the navbar:

```
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbarScroll">
        <div class="container">
          <!  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">insertgenericnamehere</a> -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#About">About</a></li>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">UX/UI</a></li>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

It doesn't look that messy in atom, I swear

Here is the css for the navbar:

I know I have too many "list-style-type", I need to remove the excess still.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

 {
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

I'm still really new to html&css so feel free to shame me for stupid stuff, but I'm honestly stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, first thing I noticed, you have `</li>` twice after each li element :) Probably some auto-complete. I'm not sure what you mean by *" fixed navbar either doesn't scroll, but the hyperlinks work"* ?

But when I try it in jsFiddle and add

```
<div id="Portfolio">
portfolio
</div>
```

It works fine for me (Ignore `<br/>s` I'm just lazy :D)
https://jsfiddle.net/kz1fxcpe/#&togetherjs=CecrBwKjSj

Edit: I know you wrote that you will be removing it, but just to be sure - only `<ul>` needs `list-style-type: none;` :) And I played with your css a little bit, I recommend to use **flex** more than float, it is much more safer, but it's probably just my preference, hope you don't mind.

```
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the help & tips. Would you generally recommend flex over float, or just this scenario? Don't apologise, it's best to learn the more functional methods now rather than building bad habits. I did figure out why only ul needs the list-style-type, but why?